# Powershell DateTimePicker not allowing custom style/color

Tags: powershell, winforms, datetimepicker

[image: Example Picture]

Trying to change the colors of my DateTimePicker. No matter what I change they are staying the default colors. Here is what I have tried,

```
    $BillDate.CalendarTitleBackColor    = 'Red' #'33, 35, 50' <- color I plan on using for background
    $BillDate.CalendarTitleForeColor    = 'Red'
    $BillDate.CalendarForeColor         = 'Red'
    $BillDate.BackColor                 = 'Red'
    $BillDate.CalendarTrailingForeColor = 'Red'
    $BillDate.CalendarMonthBackground   = 'Red'
```

I do have

```
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
[void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.Windows.Forms')
[void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.Drawing')
```

added, maybe I am just missing something else? This is being built in Powershell (PS Studio & ISE)

Comment: With `EnableVisualStyles()` the default Theme is applied and you cannot change it setting properties.

Comment: @Jimi Oh, Good to know. Thank you.